# Can I call Two procedure in php?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am using procedure in php. There are two procedure. First procedure is calling but second procedure is not working. When I comment the first procedure then second is working. 
I don't know the that two procedure are called at a time or not. please tell me the way. I am new for procedure. Please help me.

```php
if(isset($_REQUEST['customer'])){
$customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'];
$lang = 'en';

$qry = mysql_query("call customer (NULL,'$customer_name','$lang')")
  or mysql_error();//first procedure
$data = mysql_num_rows($qry);
if($data > 0){
    $msg ="Customer already exists.";
}
else{
  mysql_query("call insertCustomer(NULL,'$customer_name','','','',1,'','','','',@ret,@err_code)")
   or mysql_error();//second procedure
    $rs =  mysql_query('SELECT @p_ret,@p_err_code')or mysql_error();
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    echo $data['@p_err_code'];
    echo $data['@p_ret'];
}

 }
```

Comment: when the first procedure is called . does the message "Customer already exists." print or not ???

Comment: Does this condition: if $data triggered correctly? Do you check $msg value? Btw mysql_error can break execution.

Comment: You can write test and then check what kind of data they return(php docs assert). Btw using mysql_query is old technique, use pdo. http://us3.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not be using mysql but mysqli or PDO - mysql is deprecated and support for this will be withdrawn.

Secondly your question is not specific: the second procedure might not be called at all because `if ($data > 0)` returns true and in this case that would be ok.

Try to improve your code for debugging purposes - your calls to mysql_error() are pointless as the function returns error as a string or empty string if no error but you don't echo it out or assign it to any variables. Also would be good to save the result of mysql_query (mysqli_query rather) to a variable and then test if it worked or not.